# Conan не подхватывает conan-transit

Tags: c++, conan

Необходим пакет, который точно содержится в [conan-transit](https://bintray.com/conan/conan-transit). Делаю conan remote add conan-transit https://bintray.com/conan/conan-transit, как советует их документация, все ок, но при попытке взять то, что мне нужно ругается так:

```
ERROR: Not implemented endpoint. [Remote: conan-transit]
```

Как это исправить?

Comment: удалось выяснить, что ему не нравятся ссылки вида https://bintray.com/conan/conan-center, только https://conan.bintray.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Справа от описания репозитория есть кнопка - "SET ME UP". Если Вы нажмете на нее - получите подсказку по использованию. В Вашем случае:

```
conan remote add <REMOTE> https://api.bintray.com/conan/conan/conan-transit
```

Answer (score 0):

Путем подстановки более-менее логичных строк было обнаружено, что  https://bintray.com/conan/conan-transit это страница, позволяющая пользователям найти пакет, а сам conan может обратиться только к http://conan-transit.bintray.com/